# how to resolve an error array to string conversion

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

my model

```
public function tertinggi() {

    $sql="SELECT max(jmlnilai+case when prestasi is NULL then 0 else prestasi end) as tertinggi FROM datasiswa";

    $hasil = $this->db->query($sql);

     if($hasil->num_rows() > 0){  
      return $hasil->row_array();
     }  
    return false;
}
```

my controller

```
$data['tertinggi']= $this->m_peserta->tertinggi();

        $this->load->view('admin/v_header');
        $this->load->view('admin/v_pages',$data);
        $this->load->view('admin/v_footer');
```

my view

```
Nilai Tertinggi : <?php echo $tertinggi;?>
```

i have an error 'Message: Array to string conversion'

Answer (score 0):

So, on a good day, your `tertinggi` method returns an array, probably something like

```
['tertinggi' => n]
```

where `n` is some number.

You then assign this array to `$data['tertinggi']` which you pass to your view.

Ergo, `$tertinggi` is the aforementioned array. Try

```
<?= $tertinggi['tertinggi'] ?>
```

Or perhaps get your method to return the scalar value, eg

```
if($hasil->num_rows() > 0){  
    return $hasil->row_array()['tertinggi']; // Note: PHP 5.4 array de-referencing
}  
return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're creating an array and trying to echo it directly in your view....

```
<?php echo $tertinggi;?>
```

try looping through it instead.

```
<?php foreach($tertinggi as $row)
            echo $row['tertinggi'] ?>
```

or echo just the first row

```
<?php echo $tertinggi[0]['tertinggi']; ?>
```

give that a try instead, without knowing what the db object is returning this is just a guess. but it seems like this is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see the type that you want to print is an array
If you want to know what the type of object
 and its structure use var_dump PHP function

```
<?php var_dump($tertinggi;)?>
```

Good Luck !